# Testing a GNU Radio message accepting block with _post

Tags: gnuradio

I'm trying to write a python unit test for a GNU Radio messaging block that's conceptually very similar to `message_debug`. I noticed that `_post`ing a message to the block returns without error but has no effect. Here's `message_debug` displaying the same behavior:

```
>>> msgdbg = blocks.message_debug()
>>> msgdbg.to_basic_block()._post(pmt.intern('print'), pmt.intern("test"))
>>> msgdbg.to_basic_block()._post(pmt.intern('store'), pmt.intern("test"))
>>> msgdbg.num_messages()
0
```

I'm having trouble understanding why this happens and what steps I need to take to write a unit test for a message accepting block.

Comment: hm, are you sure your mutex is unlocked the moment you `_post`?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, good thought but when run in this way, the `_post` function returns correctly but the registered handler function never gets called at all (tested with `printf` before the mutex lock). I added an edit showing that the builtin `message_debug` block displays the same behavior: I would expect posting to `print` to print immediately, and posting to `store` to increment `num_messages` by 1. In both cases the function returns like it worked, but nothing happens.

Comment: In fact, it seems message_debug displays the issue perfectly fine so I'm going to edit my own code out of the question to make it clearer.

Comment: So; I forgot to tell you that all my unit tests for message passing just actually build a GR flow graph and run it

Comment: So, are you running a flow graph while calling `_post`?

Comment: I've read the unit test for `message_debug`, and I've tried running a flowgraph while posting to the block. It only works if the block is `msg_connect`ed to some message emitter, which makes it more difficult to unit test since you can't use `_post`. I guess I'm trying to understand better how GNU Radio handles message passing on a lower level.

Comment: ok, djanderson, I'll try to explain that handling in an answer. Stand by!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_post`ing to a block which is not part of a running flowgraph including doesn't work.

This is because GNU Radio has a thread-based scheduler, where every block lives inside his own thread, that basically goes through an infinite loop of checking in- and output streams for space, calling `general_work` as feasible, then checking whether the block has message handlers registered and and whether there are messages in the queue.

If you haven't started a flow graph, there's no thread and no loop running to check the queue.

Now, the fact that you can't use `_post` even while running in a flow graph was actually a bit surprising to me at first, but then I came to the realization that only blocks that are actually *somehow* connected actually get their own thread.

Comment: Thanks Marcus, you're a rock star :)

Comment: So in essence, `_post`ing a message to a block is analogous to manually placing some data in the input buffer: nothing actually gets processed until the scheduler calls `work` on that data. That makes total sense.

Comment: @djanderson: correct; if that makes sense: up for discussion, though ;) you can use `dispatch_msg()`, which the scheduler calls internally, but that's protected, so it won't be visible from a unit test.